# Springboot not loading the @Value annotation inside the jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, apache-kafka

I have a custom Springboot starter jar inside which I am reading a property from application.yml like below and it is working fine when I run the jar file.

```
package com.test;

@Configuration
public class Myclass {
@Value("${myapp.someProperty}")
private String someProperty;

}
```

```
myapp:
  someProperty: test
```

I have included spring.factories in the META-INF folder with the below entries:
`org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=com.test.Myclass`

but if I include this jar as a dependency in another project it's not able to read this property and throwing

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder`

I included component scan for packages of jar file like below.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.test")
public class TestApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

Is there anything am I missing?

Comment: The properties aren't in the `application.properties` (or yaml). If you included an `application.yaml` (or properties) in your starter jar that is useless as it will be ignored, only 1 `application.yaml` will be loaded and that will be the first that is found, generally that is the one in your actual application not the one from the starter.

Comment: So I should not have an application.yml file inside Jar? Instead, should I have it in the Main project only? My idea was to have common configurations inside the jar, so it could be reused and profile-specific configurations in the Main project using spring profile-specific YML files. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Don't it will not work only unpredictably. What if you have another library with "defaults" which application.yaml should be loaded? What if you add a third... Either provide a default value in the expression (as that is basically what you are doing) or explicitly document that something needs to be configured.